# Contradictory assumptions on evaluator in SICP

Tags: scheme, sicp

Exercise 1.6 defines a `new-if` with `cond`:

```
(define (new-if predicate then-clause else-clause)
  (cond (predicate then-clause)
        (else else-clause)))
```

This `new-if` would fall into infinite loop when called in a recursion.

Example `sqrt-iter` illustrates the fact that arguments are evaluated immediately after passing into a `user-defined` function.

The (infinite)`stream` introduced in 3.5 is also defined a function:

```
(define (cons-stream a b)
  (cons a
        (delay b)))
```

The key point to build it, according to the text book, is `delay`.

But supposed you build a stream:

```
(define (intgers-starting-from n)
  (cons-stream n
               (intgers-starting-from (+ n 1))))

(define integers (intgers-starting-from 1))
```

Using the same evaluator as it in `new-if`, you won't get it working because `(intgers-starting-from n)` would always evaluate `(intgers-starting-from (+ n 1))` and obviously there is no end to it despite how `delay` is implemented.

Is it contradictory that SICP assumes such evaluator that works for `cons-stream` but not for `new-if`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SICP says](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#%_sec_3.5.1):

> `Cons-stream` is a special form defined so that
>
> ```
> (cons-stream <a> <b>)
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> (cons <a> (delay <b>))
> ```

[It also adds](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#footnote_Temp_446):

> Although `stream-car` and `stream-cdr` can be defined as procedures, `cons-stream` must be a special form. If `cons-stream` were a procedure, then, according to our model of evaluation, evaluating `(cons-stream <a> <b>)` would automatically cause `<b>` to be evaluated, which is precisely what we do not want to happen. For the same reason, `delay` must be a special form, though `force` can be an ordinary procedure.

By definition, a special form is not a procedure or function. So, your definition of `cons-stream` is incorrect.

It's usually implemented as a macro:

```
(define-syntax cons-stream
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((cons-stream a b)
     (cons a (delay b)))))
```

Indeed, you can define `new-if` as a macro and it'd work correctly too:

```
(define-syntax new-if
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((new-if predicate then-clause else-clause)
     (cond (predicate then-clause)
           (else else-clause)))))
```